# Is there any code analyser for Unity?

Tags: unity, testing

I want to analyse my Unity code, as to say all of my scripts, to check if there are obvious bugs or code smells. **[SonarQube](https://www.sonarqube.org/)** does not support Unity as far as I know. I have heard of **[Gendarme](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/tools+libraries/tools/gendarme/)** but I don't know what it is worth, it is stated in this [post](https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/gendarme-for-unity-a-code-analysis-tool.112552/) that it can be used with Unity but there was no update on the GitHub repo for the last 4 years .

**Then, is there any known code analizer that use the Unity basecode and can be used in a good development workflow ?**

Comment: https://github.com/vad710/UnityEngineAnalyzer Probably the only one that i know of

Comment: I don't see why my question is off topic as it is about game development and good habits. Thanks for the comment anyway, I'll look into it :)

Comment: You are essentially asking "which technology to use" which is off-topic as described in the [help].

Comment: Well it's more is there any technology at all, since I would take the only one working. Where could I ask the question otherwise please ?

Comment: I don't think my question is in the following : "how to get started," "what to learn next," or "which technology to use". I am pretty sure many people are interested in the answer as well. I am not asking what software to use, just if some kind of code analyser exist to check my code. If this still doesn't fit in this forum, where else could I ask please ?